# How can I use random.choice in my script so I get different a different result after each button press without closing the Tkinter window?

Tags: python, tkinter, pynput

I'm working on a project which will allow me to simulate typing so I can automate email responses. For this I'm using Tkinter to create a pop-up window that is always on top of all other windows (always in foreground) with a button. After pressing the button, I have a two second pause to allow me to click into the different window and then a Pynput function referencing the string variable (the text response in the email) is executed.

In my variable I have a couple random.choice methods included with a list of synonyms to vary the word choice in the response varies each time (or most of the time). Right now when I run my script, the window appears and a response is typed although the random.choice does not execute upon each button click but rather each time I close the Tkinter window and run the script again. I would like to be able to keep the Tkinter window open and not have to re-run the script each time in order for the random.choice to work properly. How can I modify my script so that random.choice works each button click?

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import * 
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller 
keyboard = Controller()
import time
import random

def center_window(w=300, h=200):
    ws = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    hs = root.winfo_screenheight()
    x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
    y = (hs/2) - (h/2)
    root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))

rej = random.choice(["Hey", "Hello", "What's up"]) +", thanks for reaching out! 
This " + random.choice(["idea", "concept", "project"]) + " was " \ 
+ random.choice(["unique,", "interesting,", "creative,", "solid,", "clever,"]) + 
" although it doesn't quite fit our vision right now. " \
"We appreciate the submission and look forward to receiving more from you in the future."

root = Tk()
root.title('Automate')

def Reject():
    time.sleep(2)
    keyboard.type(rej)

RejectButton = Button(root, text="Reject", padx=50, pady=10, command=Reject, fg="#ffffff",
bg="#000000")
RejectButton.pack()

center_window(300, 250)
root.lift()
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)

root.mainloop()
```

Let's say that the random.choice selects "Hey", "concept" and "unique" after running the script. Then the output after each button press until closing the Tkinter window and re-running the script again will be:

> Hey, thanks for reaching out! This concept was unique, although it
> doesn't quite fit our vision right now. We appreciate the submission
> and look forward to receiving more from you in the future.

Comment: Properly explained Q, but the indentation is not correct, please fix it

Comment: The identation is not fixed so im not sure if this is the correct reason, but everything between the start of a code, till the end(`root.mainloop()`) will only be run once, during initial code execution, and you are using `random.choice()` between these points, so it will just get executed once, instead put it inside of a function and each time you call your function, it should be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a solution before fixing your indentation, try moving `rej` inside the function `Reject()`:

```
def Reject():
    rej = random.choice(["Hey", "Hello", "What's up"]) +", thanks for reaching out! 
    This " + random.choice(["idea", "concept", "project"]) + " was " \ 
    + random.choice(["unique,", "interesting,", "creative,", "solid,", "clever,"]) + 
    " although it doesn't quite fit our vision right now. " \
    "We appreciate the submission and look forward to receiving more from you in the 
    future."

    time.sleep(2)
    keyboard.type(rej)
    print(rej)
```

Though this gave me a EOL error, this is same as what you posted, or you could also say something like:

```
rej = random.choice(["Hey", "Hello", "What's up"]) +", thanks for reaching out! This " + random.choice(["idea", "concept", "project"]) + " was "  + random.choice(["unique,", "interesting,", "creative,", "solid,", "clever,"]) + " although it doesn't quite fit our vision right now. We appreciate the submission and look forward to receiving more from you in the future."
```

Whats the difference, its all in one line, while there you used in multiple lines, for which I recommend using triple quotes and `f` strings for dynamic insertion of variables, like:

```
def Reject():
    rej = f'''{random.choice(["Hey", "Hello", "What's up"])}, thanks for reaching out! 
This {random.choice(["idea", "concept", "project"])} was {random.choice(["unique,", "interesting,", "creative,", "solid,", "clever,"])} although it doesn't quite fit our vision right now.
We appreciate the submission and look forward to receiving more from you in the future.'''
    time.sleep(2)
    keyboard.type(rej)
    print(rej)
```

Everything from the start of the code till the end of the *normal* code block will just be run once, and your `rej` is in between this point, and will get executed just once, and hence that explains why it stays same through out the whole `mainloop()`, so to make it properly randomized on each button click, you have to move it to inside the function. So calling that function each time will run the `rej` each time, making it random.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm going to fix the indentation and try this out, I'll keep you posted

Comment: @DanielJerrehian Ive updated the answer with the entire code, try to check what you missed out

Comment: This is working thank you! Sorry my fault on the initial error. Appreciate your help :)